# Get value of selected row in telerik grid from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to get the value of GridBoundColumn which DataField="id" using javascript in client side. Whenever the user clicks on the image button of the row, I should retrieve the id of this row and call a web method passing this id... I have tried this script block in the same aspx page:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test(object) {
         try {
           var master = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView(); 
           var selectedItems= master.get_selectedItems()[0].getDataKeyValue("id"); 
           alert(selectedItems);
         } catch (err) {alert(err);}
      }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

But an error is thrown: cannot read property getDataKeyValue of undefined...
I found that length of selected items is 0 :

```
var selectedItems= master.get_selectedItems().length;  // selectedItems = 0
```

What is missed here? how can I get the id value? below is my telerik grid code:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Wrap="false" FooterStyle-Width="100px" PagerStyle-Wrap="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"                        GridLines="None" EnableViewState="false">
     <HeaderContextMenu EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"></HeaderContextMenu>
     <FooterStyle Wrap="False"></FooterStyle>
     <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
     <PagerStyle Visible="true" PagerTextFormat="Change page: {4}    <b>{5}</b> items in <b>{1}</b> pages" />

     <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id" ClientDataKeyNames="id"  PageSize="15" TableLayout="Fixed">

       <NoRecordsTemplate>
         <div> No records to display.</div>
       </NoRecordsTemplate>

       <Columns>
         <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="id"
                                        Visible="false">
         </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
         <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn" ItemStyle-Width="35px" HeaderStyle-Width="35px">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgUpload" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ClientIDMode="Static" data-id='<%# Eval("id") %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/Misc/File-Upload-icon.png"  OnClientClick="test(this);" TabIndex="-1" ToolTip="Upload" />
           </ItemTemplate>                                    
           <HeaderStyle Width="35px"></HeaderStyle>
           <ItemStyle Width="35px"></ItemStyle>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
      </Columns>

   </MasterTableView>
   <ClientSettings>
   </ClientSettings>
   <FilterMenu EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="False">
   </FilterMenu>
   <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="False" />
 </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**Edit:**

I have tried also this solution:

```
var imgUpload = document.getElementById("imgUpload");
var imgUpload_ID = imgUpload.getAttribute('data-id');
alert(imgUpload_ID);

var Clicked_rowIndex = object.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
alert(Clicked_rowIndex);
```

Concerning the Clicked_rowIndex: each click is returning the correct rowindex (1,2,3 ....) 
But for all rows it is displaying the same id (id of the first row);
How can I make a combination between Clicked_rowIndex and imgUpload_ID to get the id of the selected row_index?

Comment: Perhaps you should be working on the parameter "object" and not the get_selectedItems()[index] as there may be no selected row when the image is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally I found it:

```
 var Rows = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
 var Clicked_rowIndex = object.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
 var row = Rows[Clicked_rowIndex-1];
 id = row.getDataKeyValue("id");
 alert(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().get_selectedItems()[0].getDataKeyValue("Id");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!